# PHP Convert Ascii to Octal

Tags: php

I'm trying to convert a string of ASCII characters to their octal equivalent and can't for the life of me figure it out. Any one know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd just use `ord` and `base_convert`.  Use `ord` to get the ascii value in decimal, then `base_convert` to make it octal.

```
$oct = base_convert(ord($char), 10, 8);
```

Here's what you seek in the form of a function:

```
function string_to_octal($str)
{
    $chars = str_split($str);
    $rtn = "";

    foreach ($chars as $c) { $rtn .= str_pad(base_convert(ord($c), 10, 8), 3, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT); }

    return $rtn;
}
```

Note: `str_pad` is included because the result won't always be a 3-byte chunk.
Example of the above code [in action](http://ideone.com/ub1lPx).

**edit:** As @brbcoding pointed out, you can use `decoct($c)` in place of `base_convert($c, 10, 8)`.

Comment: Could you use `decoct()` instead of `base_convert()` in this situation?

Comment: @brbcoding  Absolutely.  I wasn't aware there was a `decoct` function, so I fell back to the ultra-generic `base_convert` function.

Comment: Cool... I haven't really ever run into this issue, but was trying to figure it out too. Here's that line w/ `decoct`... `foreach ($chars as $c) { $rtn .= decoct(ord($c)); }`